# AudioPlayer fails to play files

Tags: python

I tried to make something that plays an audio file using this package: https://github.com/mjbrusso/AudioPlayer

This is my code:

```
def play_file(file: str, playback: bool):
    global playback_device

    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)

    if not (os.path.exists(path)):
        print(f'No file found at path \'{path}\'')
        print('Cannot play file.')
        return

    mixer.music.load(file)
    mixer.music.play()

    if playback:
        if playback_device is not None:
            playback_device.close()
        try:
            playback_device = AudioPlayer(file)
            playback_device.play()
        except audioplayer.abstractaudioplayer.AudioPlayerError as e:
            print('Failed to start playback')
            print(e)
```

And the error I get is this:

```
Failed to play "...\out.wav", code 289
```

This is the code from the package that seemse to cause it (I slightly modified it to see the error code):

```
    def _load_player(self):
        ret = self._mciSendString('open "{}" type mpegvideo alias {}'.format(self._filename, self._alias))
        if ret > 0:
            raise AudioPlayerError( 'Failed to play "{}", code {}'.format(self.fullfilename, ret))
        return ret
```

I checked and it seems to be smth to do with the alias...?

The alias is just `"A{}".format(id(self))`

I don't even know what's causing this, it worked fine before I moved it to a different function:

```
if playback_device is not None:
    playback_device.close()
...
if speech_playback:
    playback_device = AudioPlayer('out.wav')
    playback_device.play(block=False)
```

I don't know what else to do

Comment: "I checked and it seems to be smth to do with the alias...?" That's the conclusion I came to as well. It seems that you need to use a different alias for each sound resource. `id(self)` is not going to work, because you are going to try to create multiple sound resources with the same instance of the class. But it's probably better to *store* the `AudioPlayer` instance somewhere, and `.play` it multiple times, rather than trying to create multiple instances.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is thought that it needs to be able to play multiple files, not only out.wav, and to change the path I have to create a new instance of AudioPlayer each time

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that when you said "The alias is just `"A{}".format(id(self))`", you were still talking about the library code. I thought you meant that this was inside a class in your own code. I can't see a reason for an issue, then, since you're creating separate `AudioPlayer` instances. My suggestion is to try to create a self-contained [mre] and then post **on the issue tracker for the project**; this seems more likely to be their bug than anything we can help you with.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the help though! In the meantime I just added an "aliascounter" that increments by 1 every time, hopefully that works for now, I'll post the issue on the tracker.
Thanks again for the help!